# Rspec expect a yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a hash in Rails and one of the values is a yield.

```
{
  key1: 'foo',
  key2: lambda { |p| root_path(p) },
}
```

I am not entirely sure how I can expect `key2` to receive this yield
I looked in to `yield_control` but I am not sure that is what I need.

I want to assert that `key2` receives a yield and I also want to assert what that yield returns (`root_path(p)`)

Comment: Would `expect(hash[:key2].arity).to eq 1` be ok?

Comment: I would need to know the exact route in the yield since there are more like this with different routes

Comment: Then secend expect `expect(hash[:key2]["lol"]).to eq root_path("lol")`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Add it as an answer and I can accept it

Comment: Just for the records on @BroiSatse (I also believe is a good answer): An equivalent, and perhaps clearer spell is just `expect(hash[:key2].call("lol")).to eq root_path("lol")`. Longer, but shows explicitly that the test deals with a proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be sure that key2 contains a lambda and you want to test what the lambda returns?

example of a test for a lambda

```
let(:my_hash)  = {
                   {
                     key1: 'foo',
                     key2: lambda { |p| root_path(p) }
                   }
                 }

expect(my_hash[:key2].try(:lambda?)).to be true
```

to test for result

```
expect(my_hash[:key2].call("foo")) to eq root_path("foo")
```